# cannot reshape array of size (x,) into shape (x,y,z,1)

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, shapes, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to convert a numpy ndarray with a shape of `(2200,)` to numpy ndarray with a shape of `(2200,250,250,1)`. every single row contains an image `(shape: 250,250,1)`

This is my object:

`type(x_train_left)` prints `numpy.ndarray`

`x_train_left.shape` prints `(2200,)`

`type(x_train_left[0])` prints `numpy.ndarray`

`x_train_left[0].shape` prints `(250, 250, 1)`

But for some reason when i try to reshape `x_train_left` to `(2200,250,250,1)`  i get the following error:

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2200 into shape (2200,250,250,1)`

Thank for any help, iv'e searched for duplicated subjects, but they all have different problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the very simple solution:
`np.stack(x_train_left)`

and then when i try:

`x_train_left.shape` prints `(2200, 250, 250, 1)`